# How to use find command with unknown file extension?

Tags: linux, terminal

How do I use to the `find` command on linux to locate a file where I know the file name but I don't know the file extension.

For example, I want to find the `foobar` but I don't know what extension it has.  It might be `.java` it might be `.mi`, it might be something entirely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard doesn't *have* to be at the beginning.

```
find -name 'foobar*'
```

Comment: Tiago CA's answer ensures the file will have an extension. I think it meets the criteria better.

Answer (score 1):

Can use:

```
$ find . -iname "foobar.*"
```

Another command you can try is locate you would do something like:

```
$ locate foobar | grep <directory>
```